# Why am I able to access a variable that was defined in a try-except in Python from outside the try-catch?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is an example of some Python code:

```
try:
    x = l[4]
except Exception as e:
    x = 7
    
print(x)
```

I am wondering, what is the reason that I have access to `x`? I thought that I would need to do the following:

```
# Define x
x = ''
try:
    x = l[4]
except Exception as e:
    x = 7
    
print(x)
```

But for some reason, Python does not require that? Is this a scoping thing?

Comment: Because `x` is defined in all the scenarios. You could accesses it even without assigning anything in `except` block if there wasn't an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a scoping thing, or rather, the *lack* of a scope. Python does not have block scopes; the only thing that defines a new scope in Python is a function definition. (Comprehensions do, too, but that's because they are implemented using anonymous functions.)

There is no "local" `x` in either the `try` block or the `except` block; both are the same `x` as defined before the `try` statement.

One exception: `e` *is* kind of local. It's still in the same scope as `x`, but it is unset by the `try` statement once it completes to avoid a reference cycle, just as if you had written `del e` immediately after the statement.